# Save Player Stats C#

Tags: c#

Im finally finish my Rpg Game in C# Visual Studio 2013. It remains one last thing to do :
save my player stats and inventary (that is inside the player class itself) to a file to reload it later and continue playing from that exp and level. Im a beginner and really dont know how and what/where serialize things. My game rpg text game is linked just on player stats and item inside the inventory of my player so i need to save just this things. Here comes the problem. Im gonna write a short version of my code to let you understand how my rpg is organized and to let you help me with the code i have to insert for saving things.

Just two simple classes for now. 
I have my solution "THE_GAME" with its form "Game" in my project directory , then i've added a new class library named "Engine" and i've added "Engine" ad reference for my project The_Game,so my Game uses  code in Engine project. In Engine i have a lot of classes...but for now and in a short code i wanna talk about the "Player" and "Magicians" classes . This class in Engine is "short version" :

MAGICIANS CLASS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Engine
{
    public class Magicians
    {

        public int Hp { get; set; }
        public int Defense { get; set; }

public Magicians(int hp, int defense){
            Hp = hp;
            Defense = defense;
```

PLAYER CLASS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Engine
{
    public class Player : Magicians
    {


        public int ExpPoints { get; set; }
        public int hp {get;set;}
        public List<InventoryItem> Invetory { get; set; }
        public int Level
        {
            get { return ((ExpPoints / 1000) + 1); }
        }

public Player(int exppoints, int hp,int level) : base(hp, defense){

ExpPoints = expoints;
Inventory = new List<InventoryItem>();
}
```

Ok now this is my Game class and form where i put things that my game does (outside Engine).

```
    using Engine;

    namespace Magicians_game
    {
        public partial class MagiciansGame : Form
        {



            private Player _player;

    public MagiciansGame()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

    _player = new Player(0,100,1);
    _player.Inventory.Add(new InventoryItem(......);

                lblHp.Text = _player.Hp.toString();
                lblExp.Text = _player.ExpPoints.ToString();
```

Well...now follow al the code of combat functions etc etc....
Ok my game works perferctly. What i have to do to save to a file, during the game progress, my player stats (hp exp item inventory) ? Where i have to put the `[Serializable]` tag? In Magicians or in all classes? Ok but then? what is the code and where i have to put that code to save to a file?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this article from Microsoft Support: "How to serialize an object to XML by using Visual C#" http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813 - here is explained how to serialize your objects into XML - it's one form of serialization. There are other options of course.

Once you have a serialized object you can save the result into a file.

Example:

```
Player myPlayer = new Player();
using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("player.xml"))
{
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(myPlayer.GetType());
    x.Serialize(writer, myPlayer);
}
```

Comment: This would serve better as a comment and not necessarily an answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks @NKN. Code example added.

Comment: Well. First of all thanks all. things here maybe has to be explained to me. This code posted by Quality Catalyst has to be added in my MagiciansGame class? Cause in this class i ' ve create an istance of my player : _player = new Player(0,100,1); . The question is Player _player = new Player(); is the same of _player = new Player(0,100,1); ? If i create the Player _player = new Player(); code line the prog send me an error like "Player does not contain 0 arguments construct" ---> i have to change my  _player(0,100,1) in Player _player = new Player(0,100,1) ?

Comment: @EugenioOlivieri: The example shows one possible solution. It's fairly ugly though. I would implement an isolated (testable) component that does the serialization and another one that saves and loads the player data. The serialization component needs to be called from your business workflow where you have the player data available. Once you got the serialized result send it to the component that saves it.

In regards to your question: I don't know where the trigger comes from for saving the data. The MagiciansGame class might be correct, but not from inside the constructor as in your example.

Comment: Also...in myplayer.GetTyper error "Engine.Player does not contain a  definition of GetTyper and an exstention method of GetTyper..."

Comment: @EugenioOlivieri: sorry, my mistake. The method is called GetType(). Example updated. You could also use typeof(Player) instead of myPlayer.GetType().

Comment: Ok . It works if i write this code line in MagiciansGame Class:  Player myplayer = new Player(0, 10, "Initiate", 100, 100, 100, 0, 5, 1, 10, 10);
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("player.xml"))
            {
                System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(myplayer.GetType());
                x.Serialize(writer, myplayer);
            }

Comment: This means that my Player Stats are now serialized?  and now i can call a method that save this stats when or if thers some changes in it later on in the game?

Comment: Wait. doesn't work. "Impossible serialize Engine.Player because it does not have a constructor without parameters". Well...dunno what to do in this case, maybe i will need of someone that solve/write code for me..thanks anyway fot yout help and sorry if i waste your time! Eugene

Comment: @EugenioOlivieri: Serialization means you need a parameterless constructor and you need all public properties to have a getter and setter; otherwise, it won't work. You can break this rule by writing your own custom serialisers.

Answer (score 0):

Quality Catalyst's answer is great; here is a supplementary class that will be useful in re using this method for any class you want to serialize and/or derserialize :)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

//USAGE:

//To Serialize a Serializable class:
    //string serialized = XMLManager.Save<ClassToSerialize>(classInstance);

//To Deserialize a Serializable class from a serialized string:
    //ClassToSerialize classInstance = XMLManager.Load<ClassToSerialize>(serializedString);

public static class XMLManager
{
    public static string Save<T>(T data)
    {
        XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        StringWriter write = new StringWriter();
        xml.Serialize(write, data);

        return write.ToString();
    }

    public static T Load<T>(string xmlString) where T : class
    {
        try
        {
            StringReader outStream = new StringReader(xmlString);
            XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T)xml.Deserialize(outStream);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //error here
            throw new Exception("XMLManager caught an Exception!", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So in my case i have to add the line : "string serialized" = XMLManager.Save<Player>(_player); in my main class MagiciansGame? and what i have to write in "string serialized" ? Sry for the "noob" stupid question .

Comment: string save = XMLManager.Save<Player>(_player);
and then you can save that wherever you like, PlayerPrefs is a common one.
PlayerPrefs.SetString("player_save",save);
then to load:
_player = XMLManager.Load<Player>(PlayerPrefs.GetString("player_save"));